# Accessing Javascript Nested Functions

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following Javascript. I nested another function into a main function. I tried displaying the main function so that is also executes every nested functions, but it couldn't

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>

    <html>
    <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>5 Multiplication Table</title>



    </head>
    <body>

    <script>


    function myFunction()
    {
        function operandFirst(){
            var x ="";
            for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
             {
               var x = x + "The number is "+ i;
            }
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=x;
       }

    }


    </script>

    <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Display</button>
    <p id="display"></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function declarations are scoped. You can only access them from within the scope they are defined in. (JS scope is handled at the function level, so that means you can only access `operandFirst` from inside `myFunction`).

You have to call a function for it to run.

Calling `myFunction` won't cause `operandFirst` to be called automatically. You have to have a statement that calls it.

```
function myFunction() {
    function operandFirst() {
        // snip
    }

    // Like this
    operandFirst();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the inner function lives within the scope of `myFunction`, you could always return it go  gain access to it in your `window` scope:

```
function myFunction()
{
    return function operandFirst(){
        var x ="";
        for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
         {
           var x = x + "The number is "+ i;
        }
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=x;
   }

}
```

And call it like

```
myFunction()();
```

or perhaps more readable:

```
var operandFirst = myFunction();
operandFirst();
```

However, it looks like you could make more use of an object in your case:

```
var myFunctions = {
    operandFirst: function(){
        var x ="";
        for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            var x = x + "The number is "+ i;
        }
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=x;
    }
};

myFunctions.operandFirst();
```